# Solr Indexing Error showing "EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term"

Tags: search

In Drupal 7.14, when i Index my Whole Site, Solr is showing following error:

```
AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. 
Path: /batch?id=1938&op=do StatusText: Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7539 of /project/path/includes/common.inc).
```

So when i look into the lines in `/includes/common.inc` (around lines: 7537):

```
// Explicitly fail for malformed entities missing the bundle property.
if (!isset($entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']}) || $entity->{$info['entity keys']['bundle']} === '') {
  throw new EntityMalformedException(t('Missing bundle property on entity of type @entity_type.', array('@entity_type' => $entity_type)));
}
```

- What is that chunk of code (in `common.inc`) is doing actually please?
- How can i overcome that error?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal tries to index an invalid item and throws this error. 
To find out what document is causing the error, you can implement the hook_apachesolr_index_document_build hook with a watchdog statement inside.

This is from apachesolr.api.php

```
/**
 * Build the documents before sending them to Solr.
 * The function is the follow-up for apachesolr_update_index
 *
 * @param integer $document_id
 * @param array $entity
 * @param string $entity_type
 */
function hook_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {

}
```

My guess is that the last item in your dblog will be the offending item.

Answer (score 0):

> What is that chunk of code (in common.inc) is doing actually please?

- Every entity should have an bundle, Say node is an entity and article is a bundle.Like wise taxonomy_term is an entity and vocabularies are bundle.
- The above error says that you are trying to save or process a taxonomy term without its vocabulary id or name.

> How can i overcome that error?

- To debug you can use [debug back-trace](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/quick-and-dirty-debugging)  or with a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1158322) from here just for testing.
- Check whether the term is saved or processed without its vocabulary.